# My pure javascript is not validating through form input fields any reason why?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have written a simple pure javascript form validation with if else conditions. The validation function checks user input and the number of characters entered in input fields.

An error message will pop up below the focused input field if its empty and if there's an input it will check its length until it satisfies the condition.

What I wanted to know is why the javascript code is only validating the first input field only and not the rest?

Please do not post any javascript validation libraries as I am writing my own validation function for learning purposes that includes the bassistance jquery plugin, jquery validation form and etc.

Javascript:

```
function validateForm(){
var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname"), 
lastname = document.getElementById("lastname"),
email = document.getElementById("email"),
firstnameLength = firstname.value.length,
checkLengthLast = lastname.value.length;

if(firstname == isEmpty){
        errorFirstname();
        firstname.focus();
        return false;

    } else if(firstname.value != isEmpty){
        checkLengthFirst();
        firstname.focus();
        return false;

    } else if(lastname.value == isEmpty){       
        errorLastname();        
        lastname.focus(); 
        return false;

    } else if (lastname.value != isEmpty){
        checkLastName();
        lastname.focus(); 
        return false
    } else if(email.value == isEmpty){
        alert("Please fill in your email");
        document.PersonDetails.email.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

    function isEmpty(){

        this.value == 0;
    }


    function errorFirstname(){
        var errorpara = document.createElement("p");
        errorpara.innerHTML = "Please fill in your firstname";  
        firstname.parentNode.insertBefore(errorpara, firstname.nextSibling);
        setInterval(function (){
            errorpara.style.display = "none";
        }, 2000);
        return false;   
    }

    function checkLengthFirst(){
        if(firstnameLength <= 2){       

            var errorpara = document.createElement("p");            
            errorpara.innerHTML = "Name must be more than 2 characters";            
            firstname.parentNode.insertBefore(errorpara, firstname.nextSibling);
                setInterval(function (){
                errorpara.style.display = "none";
                }, 2000);       

        }
            return false;   
    }

    function errorLastname(){
        var errorpara = document.createElement("p");
        errorpara.innerHTML = "Please fill in your lastname";   
        setInterval(function (){
            lastname.parentNode.insertBefore(errorpara, lastname.nextSibling);
        }, 2000);
        return false;   

    }

    function checkLengthLast(){

            if(lastnameLength <= 2){    
                    var errorpara = document.createElement("p");            
                    errorpara.innerHTML = "Name must be more than 2 characters";        
                    lastname.parentNode.insertBefore(errorpara, lastname.nextSibling);
                    setInterval(function (){
                    errorpara.style.display = "none";
                }, 2000);   

                }
            return false;

    }

    return true;

}
```

The HTML :

```
<form id="register" name="PersonDetails" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post" action="">
    <div>
    <label>Firstname :</label>      
    <label>Lastname :</label>       
    <label>Email :</label>      
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"  value=""  />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />      
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: i can not see any definition of isEmpty??

Answer (score 0):

The validateForm function returns when it finds an empty field and stops checking the rest.
You should introduce an isValid variable, where You store the result of the validation, and return its value after all fields are checked.

Comment: Hi Blacksonic,

I've added an isValid = true variable on the top and followed by isValid = false for each if condition.

Current problem now is the browser is giving me an error saying checkLengthLast(); is not the function even that's the duplicate of checkLengthFirst(). Any reason?

Answer (score 0):

i think your first two conditions does not allowing the rest to execute. change the length check function to return true/false.

and implement conditions as follows should solve the issue.

```
if(firstname.value != isEmpty) {
    if(checkLengthFirst()) {
        firstname.focus();
        return false;
    }
} else {
    errorFirstname();
    firstname.focus();
    return false;
}
```